# Compiler throws error; generated code missing a bracket

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Trying to populate a select list through a view model.
View Model:

```
public class CountryCity
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }
    public SelectList Cities { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private CountriesContext context = new CountriesContext();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        CountryCity cc = new CountryCity();
        var countries = from c in context.Countries
                        orderby c.Name
                        select c;
        cc.Countries = new SelectList(countries,"CountryID", "Name");
        return View(cc);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@using CascadingDropdowns.Models.ViewModels
@model CountryCity

<h2>Index</h2>
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.DropDownList("CountryID", Model.Countries, "Please select country");
        @Html.DropDownList("City", new SelectList(string.Empty, "City", "<city>"), "Please select a city", new { @disabled = "disabled" }));
    }
</div>
```

This generates error:

```
C:\Users\Jakov\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\aad61407\c9799020\App_Web_index.cshtml.a8d08dba.lv9oabqd.0.cs(97,58): error CS1513: } expected
```

Everything looks fine to me.

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: Is here one ")"   redudant?      @Html.DropDownList("City", new SelectList(string.Empty, "City", "<city>"), "Please select a city", new { @disabled = "disabled" }));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove one of the closing brackets on the below line:

```
@Html.DropDownList("City", new SelectList(string.Empty, "City", "<city>"), "Please select a city", new { @disabled = "disabled" }));
```

should be

```
@Html.DropDownList("City", new SelectList(string.Empty, "City", "<city>"), "Please select a city", new { @disabled = "disabled" });
```

Comment: Really sloppy of me. Thank you. Should I erase this question now since the error is a mistype?

Comment: @Jakov only if you start getting a lot of downvotes. The specific error you got is slightly counter-intuitive - I've gotten it a few times as well.